# SQL server programming for interview

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

our input data is - **101001101**

and i need the output like - **232332232**

how to do this in SQL server

Comment: Use Replace function

Comment: `SELECT '232332232'`. Hey, nobody said the output had to be derived from the input in any way. (On a less flippant note, this helps pin down questions like "how long can the input be" and "so what happens if one of the digits is `9`"?)

Answer (score 1):

Use Replace

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(15)='101001101'

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@input,'1','2'),'0','3')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = '101001101'

SELECT REPLACE(@str*2,0,3)
```

Comment: It give wrong result for : DECLARE @str nvarchar(max) = '404004404', replace 4 with 2 and 0 with 3

Comment: You are kidding? :) The question was for `101001101` to give `232332232` :) And what if we pass `404004404` in your query?

Comment: but answer should like that OP can use for any numbers, OP has just given example

Comment: in my answer it clear you have to change new character in select statement

Comment: your answer for current example is really nice

Comment: Thanks, but as you mentioned it is only for current example, if OP want some transformation for some string/numbers he will edit his question I guess. Or give a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use Update Statement

```
update tbl set col = case when col>0 then col+3 else col+1 end;
```